# Can I deploy with only Gitlab runner on the server?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

1.Do I need both gitlab and gitlab runner installed on the server before gitlab CI/CD will work or only one is okay?. Thanks in advance for your answer.

2. What is the difference between gitlab runner and gitlab-multi runner?

Answer (score 0):

`GitLab` is the server where you can create and manage git repositories, and where you push and pull git branches.

`gitlab-runner` is a separate program, that connects to `GitLab`. When you then use GitLab CI, `GitLab` will create a list of jobs and all connected `gitlab-runner` will pick jobs from this list. `gitlab-runner` can be installed on another server than `GitLab`

`gitlab-ci-multi-runner` is an old name for `gitlab-runner`. It was renamed in version 10 of `gitlab-runner`, as explained here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html